# Multiple request from mobile app to web API throws exception but works fine with single device

Tags: c#, sql-server, api

My web API has method which fetch huge amount of data from MS sql data base it works fine when single request is made at a time to that method but when multiple request from  multiple device are made at a same time one fetch data method  from code throws "ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open"

- This exception is not occur each time.

  What are the possible causes please help???

Comment: Each request should have a different connection.  It sounds like you are trying to share a connection between different requests.

Comment: Please show us relevant code, your question cannot be answered as is. You should check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: thanks for reply 
`ExecuteReader with CommandBehavior.Default or CommandBehavior.CloseConnection `this execute reader line throws exception